# Выполняя команду запуска php скрипта в BASH , ожидается ли её завершение?

Tags: php, linux, bash

У меня есть файл Example.sh
В этом файле написано:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  sudo php -f /var/www/SomePHP.php
  sleep 0.3;
done
```

Запускаю этот файл в бэкграунде из командной строки этой командой:

```
sudo nohup ./Example.sh &>/dev/null &
```

Ожидается ли завершение php, который был вызван, и затем выполняется команда sleep, или нет?
Если нет, то как можно заставить код ждать завершения выполнения php скрипта?

Comment: А это зависит от содержимого .php файла. Если никаких fork в нем нет, то sleep конечно выполнится после завершения. но никто не мешает php сделать fork и уйти в бакграунд

Comment: Ну так поставьте *echo* между *sudo php* и *sleep* и всё сразу станет ясным! :-)

Comment: @Sergey, не станет. Как в русской рулетке, чтобы выяснить, есть ли патрон в барабане, выстрелите себе в голову — *всё сразу станет ясным*!